# `\readlist{}` inside a table not working

Tags: tables, macros, longtable, arrays, readarray

I am writing a package, which contains the following code as its part. The problem is \readlist inside longtable environment. When I write the code, not as a macro but in the main body it works, in this, I am writing \readlist outside the longtable environment. I want to use it inside the table, please help me work it out.

Here is the code as macro, which has errors

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etextools}% for entry
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}

\NewDocumentCommand\separateswarbol{m}{\StrBetween{#1}{(}{)}[\swars] \StrBetween{#1}{[}{]}[\bols]}

\NewDocumentCommand\myformat{m}{&#1}

\NewDocumentCommand\entry{m}{
    \edef\result{\csvloop[\myformat]{#1}}
    \result \\}


\newcounter{colnum}
\newcounter{restart}
\newcounter{ithunsuru}
\NewDocumentCommand\maketabularrow{mO{1}}{%
    \setcounter{colnum}{0}%
    \setcounter{ithunsuru}{#2}%
    \setcounter{restart}{1}
    \makeatletter
    \whileboolexpr
    { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{#1}} }%
    { &\ifnum\value{ithunsuru}<#1 \theithunsuru \stepcounter{ithunsuru}\else \ifnum\value{ithunsuru}=#1 \theithunsuru \stepcounter{ithunsuru} \else  \therestart \stepcounter{restart}\fi \fi \stepcounter{colnum}
    }
}

\newcounter{kitishift}
\newcounter{countar}
\NewDocumentCommand\shiftrow{O{0}}{
    \setcounter{kitishift}{#1}
    \setcounter{countar}{1}

    \whileboolexpr
    { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{countar}}{<}{\value{kitishift}}} }%
    {& \stepcounter{countar}} 
    \setcounter{kitishift}{0}
    \setcounter{countar}{0}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{taal}{mO{1}}
{   

    \begin{longtable}{ c@{} *{#1}{c|} } 

        \maketabularrow{#1}[#2]\\

    }{\end{longtable}

}

\NewDocumentCommand\khand{O{0}m}{%
    \separateswarbol{#2}
    \readlist*\bollist{\bols}
    \readlist*\swarlist{\swars}
    \newcounter{swarstringlen}
    \newcounter{bolstringlen}
    \newcounter{spos}
    \newcounter{bpos}
    \StrCount{\swars}{,}[\swarlen]
    \StrCount{\bols}{,}[\bollen]
    \setcounter{swarstringlen}{\swarlen}
    \stepcounter{swarstringlen}
    \stepcounter{swarstringlen}
    \setcounter{bolstringlen}{\bollen}  
    \stepcounter{bolstringlen}
    \stepcounter{bolstringlen}
    \setcounter{spos}{1}
    \setcounter{bpos}{1}

    \shiftrow[#1]
    \whileboolexpr
    {test {\ifnumcomp{\value{spos}}{<}{\value{swarstringlen}}}}%
    {&\swarlist[\thespos]\stepcounter{spos}}\\
    \shiftrow[#1]
    \whileboolexpr
    {test {\ifnumcomp{\value{bpos}}{<}{\value{bolstringlen}}}}%
    {&\bollist[\thebpos]\stepcounter{bpos}} 
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{taal}{16}[9]

        \khand[1]{(प,{धंध},j, नीं)[x,z,c,v] }\\

    \end{taal}
\end{document}
```

Here is a code inside body which works.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etextools}% for entry
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}

\NewDocumentCommand\separateswarbol{m}{\StrBetween{#1}{(}{)}[\swars] \StrBetween{#1}{[}{]}[\bols]}

\NewDocumentCommand\myformat{m}{&#1}

\NewDocumentCommand\entry{m}{
    \edef\result{\csvloop[\myformat]{#1}}
    \result \\}


\newcounter{colnum}
\newcounter{restart}
\newcounter{ithunsuru}
\NewDocumentCommand\maketabularrow{mO{1}}{%
    \setcounter{colnum}{0}%
    \setcounter{ithunsuru}{#2}%
    \setcounter{restart}{1}
    \makeatletter
    \whileboolexpr
    { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{#1}} }%
    { &\ifnum\value{ithunsuru}<#1 \theithunsuru \stepcounter{ithunsuru}\else \ifnum\value{ithunsuru}=#1 \theithunsuru \stepcounter{ithunsuru} \else  \therestart \stepcounter{restart}\fi \fi \stepcounter{colnum}
    }
}

\newcounter{kitishift}
\newcounter{countar}
\NewDocumentCommand\shiftrow{O{0}}{
    \setcounter{kitishift}{#1}
    \stepcounter{kitishift}
    \setcounter{countar}{1}

    \whileboolexpr
    { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{countar}}{<}{\value{kitishift}}} }%
    {& \stepcounter{countar}} 
    \setcounter{kitishift}{0}
    \setcounter{countar}{0}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{taal}{mO{1}}
{   

    \begin{longtable}{ c@{} *{#1}{c|} } 

        \maketabularrow{#1}[#2]\\

    }{\end{longtable}

}

\begin{document}

\separateswarbol{(प,{धंध},j, नीं)[x,z,c,v]}
\readlist*\bollist{\bols}
\readlist*\swarlist{\swars}

\begin{taal}{16}[9]
\newcounter{swarstringlen}
\newcounter{bolstringlen}
\newcounter{spos}
\newcounter{bpos}
\StrCount{\swars}{,}[\swarlen]
\StrCount{\bols}{,}[\bollen]
\setcounter{swarstringlen}{\swarlen}
\stepcounter{swarstringlen}
\stepcounter{swarstringlen}
\setcounter{bolstringlen}{\bollen}  
\stepcounter{bolstringlen}
\stepcounter{bolstringlen}
\setcounter{spos}{1}
\setcounter{bpos}{1}
\shiftrow[2]
\whileboolexpr
{ test {\ifnumcomp{\value{spos}}{<}{\value{swarstringlen}}} }%
{&\swarlist[\thespos]\stepcounter{spos}} \\
\shiftrow[2]
\whileboolexpr
{ test {\ifnumcomp{\value{bpos}}{<}{\value{bolstringlen}}} }%
{&\bollist[\thebpos]\stepcounter{bpos}} 
\end{taal}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your two examples are expected to produce the same result, am I right?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Yes

Comment: But in the first example `\shiftrow[1]` is called twice, while in the second example `\shiftrow[2]` is called. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Doesn't make difference.

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem. Can you please state the specifications for the working of `taal` and `\khand`?

Comment: @egreg What do you mean by specifications?

Comment: @Girish A description in words of what the commands/environments should do for a given input

Comment: `taal` should create long table environment with 16 columns (the compulsory argument) and it should create the first row starting from 9 (optional argument) to 16 back to 1.
`\khand` input will have a string which has two parts first in `( )` and second in `[ ]`. `\khand` should produce two rows for the `taal` table from the input string. The first row should contain each character between `(` and `)` as entries and the second row should contain each character between `[ ]` as entries. The `\shiftrow` will specify from where the these new rows should start. The output should be as in 2nd code

Comment: @egreg What do you mean by an XY-problem?

Comment: @Girish An XY-problem is “I need to do Y; how can I fix it?" However who asks the question actually wants to do X. It happens that our programming habits make us look for a solution with the known tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much simpler version using only `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setmainfont{Shobhika}[
  Script=Devanagari,
  Mapping=devanagarinumerals
]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{taal}{ m O{1} }
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l__girish_khand_length_int { #1 }
  \begin{longtable}{ c @{} *{#1}{c|} }
  % make the first row
  \int_step_function:nnN { #2 } { #1 } \__girish_khand_entry:n
  \int_step_function:nnN { 1 } { #2 - 1 } \__girish_khand_entry:n
  \\
 }
 {\end{longtable}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\khand}{ O{0} r() r[] }
 {
  \girish_khand:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\int_new:N \l__girish_khand_length_int
\seq_new:N \l__girish_khand_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \girish_khand:nnn
 {
  % make the first row of \khand
  \__girish_khand_row:nn { #1 } { #2 } \\
  % make the first row of \khand
  \__girish_khand_row:nn { #1 } { #3 } \\
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__girish_khand_row:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__girish_khand_seq { , } { #2 }
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \seq_put_left:Nn \l__girish_khand_seq { } }
  \prg_replicate:nn { \l__girish_khand_length_int - #1 - \clist_count:n { #2 } }
                    { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__girish_khand_seq { } }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__girish_khand_seq \__girish_khand_entry:n
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__girish_khand_entry:n { & #1 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{taal}{16}[9]
\khand(प,{धंध},j, नीं)[x,z,c,v]
\khand[1](प,{धंध},j, नीं)[x,z,c,v]
\khand[2](प,{धंध},j, नीं)[x,z,c,v]
\khand[4](प,{धंध},j, नीं)[x,z,c,v]
\end{taal}

\end{document}
```

Note the change of syntax: the braces around `(...,...)[...,...]` aren't necessary. It could be modified to be as in the original.

The two main arguments to `\khand` are stored in a sequence, which is supplemented by empty entries at the left and the right to equal the number of columns set by the `taal` environment.

Using `\seq_map_function:NN` ensures the result is generated “all at once”, so there is no change in table cell until the cells are actually “seen”. In other words, the row is generated while TeX is in the first cell. Your problem was indeed that you started loops in one cell ending in another one, which is not possible.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Now if my input string is a series of `(..)[..]` one after another how could I loop this operation keeping in mind that after the last column the filling should star in a new row, first coulmn?

Comment: @Girish This requires a good deal of work.

Comment: Could you please point out to me how the looping for `seq` is done, I will do the rest, thanks.

Comment: @Girish Am I right in thinking that `\khand` should start a new row? What's the sense of having multiple instances of `(...)[...]`?

Comment: Now when having multiple instances of `(...)[...]` khand should start at the given position not new, when it overflows the table then it should go on a new line.

Comment: @Girish I still don't understand why not using a single set of `(...)[...]`

Comment: Because the package I am writing has such a requirement. It is a package for typesetting Indian Classical music,`(...)`  holds music notes, and `[... ]` holds the song letters, they should appear below the music notes (which we have achieved in the above code). As per Indian Classical Music, this is one set, now there will be any number of sets like this in a composition.